# Why does property created with "this.other_property" yield undefined?

Tags: javascript

Why does the following not work? According to everything I've read it looks like it should work?

```
a = {
  test: "hello",
  test2: this.test
};
```

I do a `console.log(a)` and I get `test2: undefined`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you have read but maybe try something [different](http://amzn.to/1RNUZTi). In particular this [chapter](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/ch1.md).

Comment: Your code is valid - check what this.test is just before a and it will also be undefined.

Answer (score 1):

In this example, `this` refers to the value of `this` relative to the statement `a = ...`, which is probably `window` (if you're running this in the browser, and if this is the entirety of the code).

If you wrote a constructor:

```
var A = function() {
    this.test = "hello";
    this.test2 = this.test;
};

var a = new A();
```

... the value of `a.test2` would be what you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

Because your `this` refers to the window and there is no global variable/object named test, so `window.test` is `undefined`